# What does << mean in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Looking at a line of code

```
if(display & (1<<2))
```

what does 1<<2 mean?

And am I right in thinking that & is bitwise AND operator?

Comment: You can always [check the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

Answer (score 7):

It's the [bitwise left shift operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.7.1). The operands are converted to 32-bit integers, the left operand's bits are shifted left by the number of positions defined by the right operand, and the expression's value is the result.

Here's a simple example:

```
var a = 1;
var b = a << 2; // Move the bit left by two places
console.log(b); // "4"
```

That works because in a signed 32-bit integer, `1` looks like this in binary:

```
00000001
```

If you move that bit to the left two places:

```
00000100
```

...you get `4`.